# How to get text from an element which is not interactable but visible in UI?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, playwright

I want to capture the text from a text box but getting the below error.  Am using playwright. So please let me know if there is any simple way that I can get the text from the text box.

[image]

Comment: This is said by an external extension. Can you add the `HTML` source for the element you want to interact ?

Comment: Is it visible or not, your title and the image of the error contradict each other. And show HTML so we can help you.